# Is there a monthly subscription model for iOS that resets each month?

Tags: ios, subscription, threshold

I'm launching an app that I would like to offer for free each month up to a certain usage level. If the user exceeds the threshold, the app would charge them a monthly subscription. However, I don't want the subscription to automatically renew each month. Rather, I would like the usage level to reset the following month, and if the user does not exceed the threshold, the app is free for that month.

Any creative ideas about how to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, look at Apple [Overview of In-App Purchase](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/APIOverview/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html):

> **Non-renewing subscriptions** are a mechanism for creating products with a limited duration. Non-renewing subscriptions differ from auto-renewable subscriptions in a few key ways:
>   The term of the subscription is not declared when you create the product in iTunes Connect; your application is responsible for providing this information to the user. In most cases, you would include the term of the subscription in the description of your product.
>   Non-renewing subscriptions may be purchased multiple times (like a consumable product) and are not automatically renewed by the App Store. You are responsible for implementing the renewal process inside your application. Specifically, your application must recognize when the subscription has expired and prompt the user to purchase the product again.
>   You are required to deliver non-renewing subscriptions to all devices owned by the user. Non-renewing subscriptions are not automatically synchronized to all devices by Store Kit; you must implement this infrastructure yourself. For example, most subscriptions are provided by an external server; your server would need to implement a mechanism to identify users and associate subscription purchases with the user who purchased them.

You can track the user usage and ask him to buy your *Non-renewing subscriptions** if the usage exceeds the threshold. Then at the end of the subscription you can check it again and ask him to pay again for the next month.

I would consider using **renewable subscriptions** for users that know that their  usage will 
always exceed the threshold.